# decorator pattern in drawing program

Tags: c#, design-patterns, decorator

I want to ask something about decorator pattern.

I'm trying to make software about drawing shape like : line, rectangle....
and I want to apply decorator pattern to make effect when I click on "line" in form ....This is my Implement Decorator

```
class Composite
{}
class line, rect...: Composite
{}

interface UserCommand
{
    void Excute();
}

class ClickStyle: UserCommand
{
   Composite Concrete;
   .....
}

class MoveStyle: UserCommand
{
   Composite Concrete;
   ...
}

Composite Line = new Line();
if(LineClick)
Line = new BorderStyle(Line);
if(LineMove)
Line = new MoveStyle(Line);
....
To add Effect
```

But how to remove this Effect when User NotClick, NotMove ?

Exp:
I Have Line have both Click and Move Effect And I Click Rect ...How to Remove Effect from Line?

Comment: You build the instances each time they are used.

Comment: It's first idea I think...But It's not good (many instance will create and I can't control) . Hope Anyone can explain other idea

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying. You want to add decorators that apply certain effects and you're also searching for a way to remove the decorators, if the effects are no longer needed?

Answer (score 1):

Even though the decorator pattern is a good fit for these kinds of systems, I think a plain old modifier list will serve you better if you need to be able to remove any of the current effects. All of this is opinion and not based on professional experience. I'm also assuming that you have some kind of `Draw()` or `Paint()` loop to redraw 'dirty' shapes

Consider a base shape:

```
public class BaseShape
{
    public List<BaseStyle> Styles {get;}

    //...

    public void Draw()
    {
        this.DrawMe();

        foreach(var style in Styles)
        {
           style.Draw(this);
        }   
    }

    public void AddStyle(BaseStyle style){this.Styles.Add(style);}
    public void RemoveStyle(BaseStyle style){this.Styles.Remove(style);}

    protected abstract void DrawMe(); // Child class (eg Circle) knows how to draw the shape
}

public class BorderStyle : BaseStyle
{
    public override void Draw(BaseShape shape)
    {
       // Draw a border as you would in your decorator.
    }
}
```

This will allow you to add and remove styles as well as share style instances where you know up front that styles will be the same. For example the outline that indicates that the shape is selected/active.

```
public void Main()
{
    var border = new BorderStyle(); // shared

    var circle = new Circle();
    circle.AddStyle(border);

    var square = new Square();
    square.AddStyle(border);

    // Later you want to remove the border and add a drop shadow:
    square.RemoveStyle(border);
    square.AddStyle(new DropShadowStyle());
}
```

This will also allow some optimizations for example only redrawing modifiers if their attributes have changed. For example if the border width gets updated.

This will likely also work nicely with your command system as `Execute()` can add the style and potentially `Undo()` could have the inverse algorithm i.e. remove the style.

Another benefit (depending on what your app allows) is that styles are completely separated from whatever it is that they decorate. For example, say a user creates a red 4px border style and wants to save it for future use, you could easily serialize this style and use it as a template to apply to various shapes in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is better to use State pattern in your case. Each State can has its own Decorator. Hope you catch an idea:

```
Composite Line = new Line();
if(LineClick)
Line.SetActiveState();
if(LineMove)
Line.SetOnMoveState();
```

And SetActiveState() method can be look like this:

```
void SetActiveState() {
  this.Composite.Decorator = this.Decorators[StateDecorators.Active];
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is a good approach for a drawing application. He will quickly run into an XY problem where he needs state X, Y, Z, XY, XZ, YZ... depending on the number of effects. For example if the shape must be outlined and have a drop shadow, you have to have OutlineAndShadowState. The decorator pattern is really a better fit since you can have X, Y, Z and then compose X(Y(Z)) in any manner.